# SQL Azure SPLIT AT Backend Process and Resource Throttling

Tags: azure-sql-database

When the SPLIT AT command is issued, the database is split into 2 new federated members. Will these 2 members sit on the same server? will they have the same amount of I/O, CPU resources? If the application will have to grow to 50 members, is there anything else needed aside from SPLIT AT command to scale out? Will these 50 members be split across multiple servers? Is there a separate SQL Azure Server account needed for this operation?

What are the quantifiable limits when the Resource Throttling kicks in with the SQL Azure?

Answer (score 2):

One correction to David's note: all federation members are distributed to the sql azure cluster so **members don't reside on the same physical server**. Federation member are regular databases in the system and they are distributed the same way all dbs in the env behave in placement. All dbs including members are placed in the cluster through the sql azure load balancing engine by looking at their resource utilization. I talk about this [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/video/Video/hh872892).

Comment: this is a very important clarification. +1

Answer (score 0):

Yes, each federation is on the same database server, just separate databases.

Specifics around throttling are now in the SQL Azure Wiki, with a recent MSDN blog post talking about the various wiki updates [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/06/04/sql-azure-connection-management-wiki-updated-with-throttling-and-long-transaction-limits.aspx).

Comment: When it will scale out to multiple servers?

Comment: That's a roadmap question (and a good question). Unfortunately I'm not at liberty to discuss anything beyond what's published.